# Spring JPA: Update without existing Id?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am using Spring-Boot and JPA.

For saving and also updating a record there is the one method save of CrudRepository.

I use a generated long id for primary key of my record.

Now I need to update a already existing record. That will fail with an duplication exception if the primary key id does not
match the value that is already in the database. If no id is given JPA would assume an insert and that fails because the old record already exists.

So what is the best strategy for that?

I do not want to look for the id of the existing record before doing a save for updating my record.

Is there some default value for id that I an use for marking it for update instead of insert?

Comment: upsert is what you are describing and is not a best practice in concurrent applications; it works for data dump type operations, but the risk of overwriting a row with stale data grows with upsert. With Insert, you are clear that this record must not already exist. WIth update, you are stating it MUST exist, and can add other logic to check versions. What you want is certainly possible, but requires provider and database specific code that would perform a basic statement operation, negating most of the benefits and required behavior of JPA

Comment: JPA/Spring handle this with merge functionality, which checks if the ID exists and merges the data into the managed instance, or creates it. I don't understand your usecase where no ID is given - if the entity you are calling save on doesn't have identity, it does not already exist. Identity IS the entity. So the issue seems more to be with what you use to define your entity with; maybe use a natural Identifier as the ID instead of a sequence/generated one. Or implement control logic to look up the entity using your own criteria so you don't need to pass around IDs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Hibernate has such functionality. Some databases support this with their native capabilities (`insert ignore` in MySQL or `on conflict do nothing` in Postgres), but you'd have to write SQL yourself. And some databases don't have this feature at all.

Probably, the only way to do this with Hibernate is to handle constraint violation exceptions. Note though if it happens, you may not be able to proceed with the transaction/session since Hibernate warns you that Session/EntityManager can't be further used reliably if it threw an exception.